# Viol Tuning lowest note

Tags: pitch, viola-da-gamba

Are there any instruments of the viol family that can reach C1 in pitch? I have tried searching it up online but I can't find any results.

Comment: Do you mean "[viol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viol)" (i.e., viola da gamba) or "violin"?

Comment: I am referring to the viola da gamba, and the lower-pitch instruments in its family.

Comment: According to this wiki article the violone in D is the lowest at D1. Scroll down to the chart in the “tuning” section. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viol

Comment: In this way, it is compatible. I have the keyboard part at 466hz, and the violone at 415hz. If the temperament is set correctly, then the violone has the C1 of the keyboard. THank you

Comment: Bach writes that low C in the Brandenberg Concertos. The six-stringed contrabass gamba is discussed briefly [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/841865?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3A2dbbbcc607ef074e44a05aea1b2f77cf&seq=4#page_scan_tab_contents).

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Although *technically* this would be considered a *violone*, not a *viola da gamba*, because these instruments are to large to play while holding them between the legs.

Comment: Viola da gambas comes in different sizes. The bass viol has D as lowest note, one whole tone above the cello. The 7-string bass viol has an extra A string under that.

Comment: @Lazy Actually, the *violone* counts as part of the viol family. The *-one* suffix just denotes bass, as the *lirone* is a bass *lira da braccia*, even though it was held on the legs. Praetorius labels one instrument "Lirone, the large bass viola-da-gamba." And also, when you get into "historical bass bowed strings" it gets super complicated, with shoulder straps, various registers, numbers of strings, and lengths; see [my dissertation](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/149242166.pdf), pages 67 and following.

Comment: @AndyBonner No, the *violone* comes from *viola*, not *viol* (which is not an italian term), and means as much as "large fiddle".

Comment: Way off-topic, but a NS 5-string goes down to B ,  which I think is B0  https://thinkns.com/instrument/ns-design-electric-upright-bass/ns-design-electric-upright-bass-wav/

Comment: @Lazy Sorry, I wrote "Lirone" in my quote of Praetorius where I meant "violone." He explicitly uses the word "_violone_" with "_Groß Viol-de-Gamba-Baß_."

Comment: @AndyBonner You should be aware the the violone – while often associated with the da gamba family – has been used for many different instruments in different times, including viole da gamba in the tenor and bass range (as well as those big great bass instruments, playing up to a fifth below the bass instruments). But when Bach adds a great violone to his Continuo chances are high he does not think of it as part of the da gamba family (considering the strings are all part of the da braccia family).

Comment: @Lazy Yeah, that's kind of the point of my comment and answer: there's little homogeneity in physical form or terminology among "low bowed strings" throughout the renaissance and baroque. I won't venture a guess about how Bach would have conceptualized it, but I will say that my local violone-player for period Bach concerts uses a 5-string instrument with frets. :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's a pretty good argument for considering the modern concert string bass to be a "member of the viol family," and although the standard 4-string tuning puts the lowest string at E1, many instruments use a "range extender" normally tuned to C1, or have an extra string, in which case tunings often start at B0 or C1 (see [Wikipedia on bass tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_bass#Tuning).

Of historical instruments, the term *violone* covers a multitude of non-standardized, low-pitch bowed string instruments (see pages 67 and following [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/149242166.pdf)); some were closer to modern cello range, but [many of them went that low](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violone).